# C# Install - Change a custom folder location using install dialog

Tags: c#, windows, deployment, .net-3.5

I am trying to install a windows service using a visual studio setup project. All is going well except I want the user to be able to use the install dialog to specify the location of a custom folder to be created during installation.

I've added a Textboxes dialog that stores a folder location in an Install Property (`PATHPROPERTY` in this example) but I can't figure out how to use that to change the path of a folder I'm creating during the installation. I set the 'Default Location' Property of the custom folder in the 'File System' menu to:

`"[PATHPROPERTY]\folder"`

But when I change the path in the install dialog, the folder is created at the default location of `PATHPROPERTY`, not what I change it to during install. So it seems like the folder is created before I reach the point in my dialog where I ask for the path.

I noticed that there is a Property Property for the folder that I can set and supposedly use to modify the location of the folder during installation, and I've seen some articles suggesting that this can be used to set the location using a command line flag. But I would like to be able to use the install dialog, then possibly set this property in my installer class, but I haven't found any documentation on how to do that yet..

I also found something about Session.Property to set the property but [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wasn't clear on how to use this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Oh. Also. I'm targeting .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So PATHPROPERTY returns the custom folder location user has selected, If thats the case you have to set that property to "Property" attribute.

Also make sure in the User Interface Editor you are getting the user input before installation starts. (You can move up and down the UI to required position)

Comment: Well technically, I want to have PATHPROPERTY return the custom folders parent directory, then I will create the custom folder as a subdirectory of the PATHPROPERTY.

The dialog is appearing immediately after the 'Welcome' dialog and right before the 'Installation Folder' Dialog.

Comment: I tried setting the 'Property' property of the Custom Folder to the same name as the dialog input Property (i.e. PATHPROPERTY). But that didn't work either, I think that's what you were suggesting.

Comment: Yes thats what i suggested, If PATHPROPERTY returns the right value then this should work. because i have done the same couple of days back and it works fine.

Comment: If you couldnt get this done i can suggest one more approach, its not stright forward, Trying adding an installer class and override the Install method and have your logic there to create custom folders that you required in the target machine ?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Except I used the Windows Installer Custom Folders to create the folder at a default location then moved the folder to the User specified location after install in the Installer Class' Commit function. Thanks a lot for your help though!